# File names cakephp structure for person

Tags: cakephp

what is the right File names cakephp structure for person:

database table:people
model:Person
view:People
controller:PeopleController

ou bien 
database table:persons
model:Person
controller:PersonsController
view:Persons

ou bien
database table:people
model:Person
controller:PersonsController
view:Persons

Comment: Please always mention the CakePHP version that you are using and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: croogo version 1.4.4

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be singular `Person` for the model and plural `People` for the controller, views and table.

So you would have:-

- table: `people`
- model: `Person`
- controller: `PeopleController`
- view folder: `People`

Models always use the singular form of the word.

English can be a little quirky with its pluralization of words. CakePHP has [a handy online tool](http://inflector.cakephp.org/) for checking these. Give it a try with the word ["Person"](http://inflector.cakephp.org/person).

Comment: The requested address was not found on this server.